# Insertar parámetros en route Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, controller

quisiera insertar parámetros dinámicos en una ruta que tengo. Mi código es el siguiente:

BLADE:

```
<input name="idempresa" id="idempresa">
<input name="idingreso" id="idingreso">

<a id="btn-ingresos-show" href="{{ URL('ingresos-show', 'idempresa' =>  INPUT: idempresa, 'idingreso' => INPUT: idingreso]) }}"></a>
```

RUTA:

```
Route::get('ingresos-show/{idempresa?}/{idingreso?}','Empresa_IngresoController@showIngreso');
```

Si alguien me pordría ayuda por favor, estaría muy agradecido.